# Counting: Indistinguishable balls to distinguishable boxes

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem in which there are 10 distinguishable boxes, 5 indistinguishable balls are going to be put in randomly.

Could someone please explain how I would solve this problem without simply giving me the equation: C(n+k-1, k-1) or please explain the equation?

Answer (score 3):

This is an application of the stars and bars trick.

See Theorem Two in:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

We can visualize the balls as stars *, and the boxes the spaces between bars |. So something like

$*|***|**| ... $

represents one ball in the first box, three balls in the second box, two in the third, etc.

Then this reduces to figuring out how to choose the placement $k-1$ bars from a total of $n + k-1$ symbols (of either a star or a bar), which is simply $C_{n+k-1}^{n} = C^{k-1}_{n+k-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Line up the ten boxes.  Let $x_k$ denote the number of balls in the $k$th box.  Then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 + x_9 + x_{10} = 5$$
A particular solution corresponds to the placement of nine addition signs in a row of five ones.  For instance, 
$$+ + + 1 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + + +$$
means that two balls are placed in the fourth box, while one ball each is placed in the fifth, sixth, and seventh boxes; and 
$$1 + 1 + 1 + + 1 + + 1 + + +$$
means that one ball each is placed in the first, second, third, fifth, and seventh boxes.  The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can select nine of the fourteen symbols (five ones and nine addition signs) to be addition signs, which is 
$$\binom{5 + 9}{9} = \binom{14}{5}$$
In general, if we wish to place $n$ indistinguishable balls in $k$ distinguishable boxes, then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$$
so a particular solution corresponds to the placement of $k - 1$ addition signs in a row of $n$ ones.  The number of solutions is the number of ways we can select which $k - 1$ of the $n + k - 1$ symbols ($n$ ones and $k - 1$ addition signs) will be filled by addition signs, which is 
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$$

Comment: Thanks N.F.Taussing for nice explanation.